# What is pingsender and why does it wants to connect to?

Tags: macos, firefox, ping

I use Firefox and I got this message from Little Snitch.

What is `pingsender` and why does it wants to connect to incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org?

[image: Little Snitch window]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pingsender is a component of Firefox used by Mozilla for telemetry.

> The ping sender is a minimalistic program whose sole purpose is to deliver a telemetry ping.

- https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/telemetry/docs/internals/pingsender.rst